# What does this error mean?

Tags: windows-error-reporting

I am getting the following error when I boot Windows. ( Win-7 )

What does it mean & would it hurt ? How do I get rid of it ?

**jusched.exe
The file or directory C:\Userss\A\AppData\Local\Temp\jusched.log is corrupt and unreadable.Please run the Chkdsk utility.**

Thanks

Comment: "How do I get rid of it ?" - Run the chkdsk utility.  However, the message itself, is a sign of severe system file corruption.  Windows 7 does not have the same tools to repair itself that newer versions of WIndows has.

Comment: Is it `C:\Userss\...` (double s) mistake or this is as it is on your system?

Comment: It is as it is when I start the computer. How long will chkdsk will take & will it just check only C: or all drives ?

Comment: The time it takes depends on the drive size and how broken it is. Chkdsk can only do 1 drive at a time.

Comment: As "jusched" appears to be part of Java and its update function, you might try to uninstall, reboot, then reinstall Java - *assuming that you have no other trouble with the disk in question.*

Comment: I willl uninstall JAVA. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the [Java Update Scheduler](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/what-is-juschedexe-and-why-is-it-running/) *jusched.exe* cannot read its logfile *jusched.log* because of a filesystem error.

You should run `chkdsk /r` in cmd.exe and schedule it for the next reboot by [confirming](/a/287116) with `Y`. It might not be the only filesystem error so this is very recommended.

Furthermore you can disable the Java Update Scheduler via Control Panel → Java Control Panel → Update → "Check for Updates Automatically".

---

From the [Oracle Java Windows FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/windows-faq.html):

> Q: I found two processes — jucheck.exe and jusched.exe — running in the
> background of my system after installing JRE. Is there a way to shut
> them down?
>
> A: jusched.exe is the scheduler process of Java Update; jucheck.exe is
> the process for checking/performing updates in Java Update. These
> processes run automatically and transparently to users. To shutdown
> these processes, simply uncheck the "Check for Updates Automatically"
> checkbox in the Update tab of Java Control Panel.